# Solution of $y'' + 2y' + 2y = f(t)$ with $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By the method of variation of parameters, show that the solution of the initial value problem $$y'' + 2y' + 2y = f(t), \quad y(0) = 0, \quad y'(0) = 0$$

is:
$$y(t) = \int_0^t e^{-(t-\tau)}f(\tau)\sin(t-\tau)\,d\tau$$

I have absolutely no idea how to start this, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have the solution. Why don't you try to differentiate (twice) the function proposed and see if it satisfies the differential equation (and the conditions at $t=0$)?

Comment: @user37238 Because this would be a verification. I guess that Sylvia is looking for a solution of her problem.

Comment: @Siminore Indeed, I forgot the beginning of the question ("By the method of variation of parameters").

Comment: A good start would be looking up "method of variation of parameters." This would give you the first few lines of Dylan's solution below. If you have read the method, then where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2 solutions to the homogeneous equation are $y_1(t) = e^{-t}\sin t$ and $y_2(t) = e^{-t}\cos t$

Using variation of parameters, we suppose that the particular solution has the form $y_p(t) = u_1(t)y_1(t) + u_2(t)y_2(t)$

where $u_1(t)$ and $u_2(t)$ satisfy the following conditions
$$ u_1'y_1 + u_2'y_2 = 0 $$
$$ u_1'y_1' + u_2'y_2' = f(t) $$

where $y_1' = e^{-t}(\cos t - \sin t)$ and $y_2' = e^{-t}(-\sin t -\cos t)$

Solving the above system gives
$$ u_1' = -\frac{y_2(t)f(t)}{W(t)} = f(t)\,e^{t}\cos t $$
$$ u_2' = \frac{y_1(t)f(t)}{W(t)}= -f(t)\,e^{t}\sin t $$

where $W(t) = y_1y_2' - y_2y_1' = -e^{-2t} $

Thus
$$ u_1(t) = \int_0^t  f(\tau)e^{\tau}\cos \tau \,d\tau + c_1 $$
$$ u_2(t) = -\int_0^t f(\tau)e^{\tau}\sin \tau \,d\tau + c_2 $$

and the general solution is
$$ y(t) = e^{-t}\sin t \left(\int_0^t f(\tau)e^{\tau}\cos \tau \,d\tau + c_1\right) + e^{-t}\cos t \left(-\int_0^t f(\tau)e^{\tau}\sin \tau \,d\tau + c_2 \right) \\
= \int_0^t f(\tau)e^{-t+\tau}(\sin t \cos\tau - \cos t \sin\tau)d\tau + c_1e^{-t}\sin t + c_2e^{-t}\cos t \\
= \int_0^t f(\tau)e^{-(t-\tau)} \sin(t-\tau)d\tau + c_1e^{-t}\sin t + c_2e^{-t}\cos t $$

Initial values $y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 0$ gives $c_1 = c_2 = 0$